A one-sided discrete intermediate value theorem
In this post the author states a discrete version of the Intermediate Value Theorem as follows:

For integers $ a < b $, let $ f $ be a function from the integers in $ [a, b] $ to $ \mathbb{Z} $ that satisfies the property, $ |f(i + 1) - f(i)| \leq 1 $ for all $ i $. If $ f(a) < 0 < f(b) $, then there exists an integer $ c \in (a, b) $ such that $ f(c) = 0 $.

In this post a one-sided discrete intermediate value theorem was proposed:
Let $f$ be an integer-valued function defined on the integers in $[a, b]$.
(1) If $ f(i + 1) - f(i) \geq -1 $ for all $ a≤i≤b-1 $ and $ f(b) < 0 < f(a) $, then there exists an integer $ c \in (a, b) $ such that $ f(c) = 0 $.
(2) If $ f(i + 1) - f(i) \leq 1 $ for all $ a≤i≤b-1 $ and $ f(a) < 0 < f(b) $, then there exists an integer $ c \in (a, b) $ such that $ f(c) = 0 $.
Then my question is about the validity of this result since I am not confortable with it.

@CameronBuie: Ok, it is written.

Intuitively this seems fine. Can you share your reasons for being not comfortable with it?

@BenjaminWang:  a proof is required for the two statements.

To develop an intuition about it, it's important to unpack what the symbolic stuff actually means. In this case, we're saying that $f$ is a function that takes as inputs the integers $a$ and $b,$ as well as any and all integers between them, then assigns to each input some integer output. In particular, for all 3 of the claims, the outputs corresponding to $a$ and to $b$ are on opposite sides of $0.$
Considering the first claim only, we have moreover that from one integer input to the next, the output value never changes by more than $1$--that is, it may drop by $1,$ it may stay the same, or it may climb by $1,$ but those are the only things that may happen.
When I imagine such a function, starting the inputs at $a$ and increasing them by $1$ each time, I see that it might wander around for a time with all outputs being on the same side of $0,$ at first. However, it eventually has to end up on the other side from where it started, and it only has a finite number of inputs, so it can't do it forever, and will eventually swap sides for the first time. The limitation in step size would mean it will necessarily land only one step away from $0$ for this first output on the opposite side, and that the output must have been at $0$ for the prior input.

Here's an outline of how one might go about proving it.
One can use the Well-Ordering Principle to prove that if $A$ is a subset of the set $\Bbb Z$ of all integers and $A$ has a least element, then given any non-empty subset $B$ of $A,$ the set $B$ must have some least element.
With the above fact in mind, to prove the Discrete IVT, the gist is to observe that $$A:=\{j\in\Bbb Z\mid j\geq a\}$$ is a subset of $\Bbb Z$ which has a least element (namely, $a$), and since $$B:=\bigl\{j\in A\mid f(j)>0\bigr\}$$ is a non-empty subset of $A$ (because $b\in B$), then $B$ has a least element, say $k.$ That is, there is an integer $k$ such that:

$k\geq a,$
$f(k)>0,$ and
for all integers $j,$ if $j\geq a$ and $f(j)>0,$ then $j\geq k.$

Since $k\geq a$ and $f(k)>0>f(a),$ then $k\neq a,$ so $k>a,$ and thus $k\geq a+1.$ (Do you see why?)
Hence, $k-1\geq a,$ and $k-1$ is an integer. If we had $f(k-1)>0,$ it would follow by condition 3 above that $k-1\geq k,$ which is ridiculous; therefore, $f(k-1)\leq 0<f(k).$ Consequently, $$1\leq f(k)-f(k-1)=\bigl|f(k)-f(k-1)\bigr|.$$ (Do you see why?)
By our initial "step size" hypothesis on $f$ (with $i=k-1,$) we then have $f(k)-f(k-1)=1,$ so $f(k)-1=f(k-1).$ Since $f(k)$ is positive, then $f(k-1)\geq 0,$ but since $f(k-1)\leq 0,$ then $f(k-1)=0.$ All that remains is to show that $k-1<b,$ which is straightforward.

To prove the two one-sided versions, one can proceed along similar lines. The main difference to notice is that those claims only limit the step size in one direction to $1,$ and allows them to be arbitrarily large in the other direction.
